# Using a custom font without installing

Tags: java

I'd like to use (several) custom fonts in my project. Here's the code snippit:

```
package Panes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MainPane extends GradientBackground {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MainPane() {

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    try {
        ge.registerFont(
                Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("fonts/space age.ttf")));
    } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1500, 750);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(115, 50, 50, 50));
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setContentPane(this);

    JLabel compName = new JLabel("O-Nut Industries");
    compName.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    compName.setFont(new Font("Space Age", Font.PLAIN, 86));
    compName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel divName = new JLabel("Aerospace Division");
    divName.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    divName.setFont(new Font("Space Age", Font.PLAIN, 38));
    divName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel progName = new JLabel(" Automated Launch System ");
    progName.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    progName.setFont(new Font("Enter The Grid", Font.PLAIN, 64));
    progName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    JButton launchBtn = new JButton("LAUNCH");
    launchBtn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    launchBtn.setFocusable(false);
    launchBtn.setFont(new Font("neuropol", Font.PLAIN, 68));
    launchBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            frame.setContentPane(new LaunchPane(frame));
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    JButton abortBtn = new JButton("ABORT");
    abortBtn.setBackground(Color.RED);
    abortBtn.setFocusable(false);
    abortBtn.setFont(new Font("neuropol", Font.PLAIN, 68));
    abortBtn.setMaximumSize(launchBtn.getPreferredSize());

    abortBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            new AbortPane();
        }
    });

    add(compName);
    add(divName);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 100)));
    add(progName);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 100)));
    JPanel btnPane = new JPanel();
    btnPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btnPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    btnPane.add(launchBtn);
    btnPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 0)));
    btnPane.add(abortBtn);
    btnPane.setOpaque(false);
    add(btnPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
}

static void init() {
    new MainPane();
}
}
```

I've used this method before successfully, but for some reason I'm getting a "java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.". The resource folder (fonts) was created with my project folder as the parent, so I'm almost positive the path is correct. Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Thanks.

EDIT-

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
at Panes.MainPane.<init>(MainPane.java:30)
at Panes.MainPane.init(MainPane.java:107)
```

I'm using Win 10 and Java SE v 8 as it's on an x86 system, and Eclipse IDE 18-09.

EDIT2 -

So I got it to work by taking the .ttf files and putting them directly into my src folder, then removing the fonts/ portion of the path like so:

```
getResourceAsStream("space age.ttf")
```

I was under the impression the file path would be relative to the project folder and not the src folder, but I guess not. Either way, works now. Thanks all.

Comment: Is there no more detail in the stacktrace? I expect there to be a "Cause:" section a few lines down into the stacktrace with more useful information as to the "why" of the error. If there is no more information, then it will be very hard to help you without having the actual font, and details about the JDK version, OS and OS version.

Comment: Please edit your question with new information. Comments are for discussion about the question

Comment: If you know how to use the debuggger in Eclipse, you may want to set a breakpoint in createFont0. This is a case in which the JDK is throwing away the cause of an exception - very bad form. Search for "Problem reading font data." in the source, and set a breakpoint there. Check what exception is in the `Throwable t` that was caught just before it.

Comment: Sorry, so I set the breakpoint at line 30 (createFont()) and ran the debugger, but where am I searching for "Problem Reading Font Data"?

Comment: Is your project folder on the classpath? The resources must be on the classpath to be accessed in this way.

Comment: When I added the folder I right clicked on the Project Folder>Properties>Java Build Path>Source(tab)>Add Folder>Create New Folder, then created the folder. Do I need to modify it independently? Sorry, this method is new to me.